# How can I get a first-person perspective / satnav look for my ReactNative map app?

Tags: react-native, routes, gps, maps, react-native-maps

[image: SatNav Screen]

I want my app to display this type of look.

I have tried using animateBearing, animateToViewingAngle but none of those seem to do enough. It doesn't zoom in enough and if I set the angle to be flat, it zooms out really far. I want the view to be basically street level and center the user onto the screen, and keep the view in the same direction the user is facing.